Elliptic regularity with negative Sobolev space on bounded or unbounded domains
I am looking for some reference which deals with the existence and regularity of solution to $ -\Delta u = f $ in bounded or unbounded domain $\Omega$  and with Dirichlet boundary condition, $u|\partial \Omega = 0$ where $f \in W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$ (or some other negative sobolev space in general)

I highly recommend François Treves' and Hörmander's books on these topics, but the ones you need are:

Treves, F. (1975). Basic Linear Partial Differential Equations. Academic Press. In Chapter 3, it discusses this exact problem, although only in the case $f \in W^{-1, 2}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is bounded.
Agranovich, M. S. (2015). Sobolev Spaces, Their Generalizations and Elliptic Problems in Smooth and Lipschitz Domains. Springer. This text delves into Dirichlet problems for elliptic operators in general, but also only considers the case $f \in W^{-1, 2}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain.
Simader, C. G., & Sohr, H. (1996). The Dirichlet Problem for the Laplacian in Bounded and Unbounded Domains. CRC Press. This book discusses a slew of related problems, but there is no mention of such $W^{-1, p}$ spaces.

I also skimmed many other articles and books, and as far as I can tell, there is no systematic investigation of the case where $f \in W^{-1, p}(\Omega)$, beyond the special case where $p = 2$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain.

Thanks for the references, I will look through these.

A very classical and comprehensive reference which also deals with the case of negative Sobolev spaces would be Jerison & Kenig: The Inhomogeneous Dirichlet Problem on Lipschitz Domains.

@Hannes - Thanks a lot for the reference. Also do you know any reference for theorem 0.3 in this paper of Jerison & Kenig, it would be very helpful as I am also not aware of this result.
